# What is あーんしちゃろうか？

Tags: translation

At the bottom of this picture it says あーんしちゃろうか？

http://ameblo.jp/maofish/entry-10957305590.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
「あーんしちゃろうか」 = あーん　して　やろう か 
 Shall I give you a mouthful?
```

At first I also thought it might be 「してしまう」 but only something very unhealthy (i.e. a guilty pleasure) would justify this. The 高菜チャーハン (たかなちゃあはん) seemed pretty healthy to me.

On further examination (and checking with a native speaker) we concluded it's **して + やろうか**

The ちゃ sound results from mixing the て+や very quickly into しちゃ.

Here's an example from the wild:
「。。。おか〜ちゃんがダッコしちゃろうか（ダッコしてやろうか）」

**Ref: http://koryu04.exblog.jp/7853917/ + bonus material, this page has pictures of puppies!**

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, given that して+しまう+volitional would be してしまおう→しちゃおう **not** しちゃろう.